# Autoplay Bluray with VLC

Tags: windows, vlc-media-player, blu-ray, autoplay

VLC can support Bluray playback after installing two small files in the right directories.

**However**, when you insert a bluray disc, you can't right click and play with VLC.
You have to launch VLC, open disc, choose bluray, choose driver, and ok.

I was wondering if there is anyway to have the bluray autoplay with VLC with a little hacks.
I'm sure something could be done to get vlc to automatically execute a command line or what so ever to simulate the steps, when a bluray has been inserted.

I'm not familiar with command lines at all, but if anyone has any clues?

Comment: Think this may be more appropriate under SuperUser

Comment: Is this Windows?

Comment: Yes sorry, on windows right

Answer (score 3):

This is not an autoplay solution, but you can do something to make opening Blu Rays on VLC a bit easier. Create a VLC shortcut on Windows with the second parameter pointing to your Blu Ray drive. Double clicking the shortcut should automatically start the movie.

So create a new shortcut wherever you want, like your desktop, and paste this to the Target:

```
"C:\Program Files\VideoLAN\VLC\vlc.exe" bluray:///d:\
```

Remember that you need the quotes if you have spaces in the path, which you probably have because of "Program Files". That bluray protocol is undocumented in the VLC Command Line help, but it should work. Replace the  drive letter (in my case d:) with whatever letter you have as the Blu Ray drive.

Answer (score 3):

I got autoplay to work for Bluray's in Windows 7 with VLC 3.x.

I can't see any reason this wouldn't work with other versions as well. There is a registry key for playing the DVD drive with VLC. Mine was:

```
HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\DVD\shell\PlayWithVLC\command
```

The command line data for this key was:

```
"C:\Program Files\VideoLAN\VLC\vlc.exe" --started-from-file dvd:///%1
```

Open up Regedit, find the key, and change the 'dvd' part to 'bluray', but keep the rest of the syntax, like so:

```
"C:\Program Files\VideoLAN\VLC\vlc.exe" --started-from-file bluray:///%1
```

And voila, autoplay worked perfectly, for both Bluray AND regular DVDs. So no need for creating an icon shortcut.

Answer (score 0):

To play Blu-ray with VLC on Windows, besides upgrading to VLC 3.0 or greater, you'll need to download the VLC Windows 64bit version if you're suing a 64bit Windows computer. Moreover, it would be better to keep the default installation path while installing VLC.To play Blu-ray with VLC more smoothly, you can use DumboFab to digitize your Blu-rays to MP4, MKV. It would be easier to play.